# How should i set null dates

Tags: postgresql, null

I've some null dates in database (PostgreSQL). In program this records gives me null pointer exception.

How should i set these dates? Something like 01-01-1900 or what?

Comment: Can you share the code that produces the `NullPointerException` please?

Comment: Should there be rows with no dates? If so their being `null` is correct and your code should account for that. If not, the schema should enforce that by setting the column to `not null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is the correct way to represent an unknown value. If your code can't handle that you should fix your code. Storing "magic" values in the database is rarely a good decision.

---

Having said that: if you are doing range queries on that `date` column (e.g. things like: `where the_date_column > current_date - 42` or `where the_date_column between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-04-08'`), then having values other than `NULL` to represent a date in the future (or past) sometimes does make sense (because you avoid the `or is null` predicate which usually prevents the use of an indx).

If you **never** use that value for range queries (so you always compare it with `=`) then stick to `NULL` and fix your code.

If you do have those types of queries, you might want to have a look into Postgres' `infinity` value which represents a date value that is greater than any other value (and `-infinity` for one that is smaller than all others).

So if your date value represents, e.g. a "valid until" date and `null` means "valid indefinitely" then using `-infinity` might make sense:

```
insert into some_table
  (some_value, valid_from, valid_until)
values
  (42, '-infinity', 'infinity');
```

The next question is whether your code would be able to handle that though.

---

If you regularly have the pattern of a start **and** end date, you might want to replace that with a single `daterange` column. For a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) type a `NULL` value is the equivalent for "unbounded". Even if the lower and upper bound of a range is `NULL` the range value itself is not null

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into some_table (some_id, some_date_column)
values
(42, NULL);
```